# C# Assembly Load loading the wrong assembly

Tags: c#, .net, .net-assembly, appdomain, assembly-loading

> I've already seen questions about dynamically loading assemblies

Basically, I want to do 3 things:

1) Dynamically load a user-selected (managed) assembly

2) Modify the assembly (in the program itself)

3) Replace the loaded assembly with the new one

**The below code loads the correct assembly:**

```
System.Reflection.Assembly myDllAssembly = System.Reflection.Assembly.LoadFile(assemblyPath);
```

But, as far as I know, to replace the file, I'll first need to unload it to remove the file handle. So I tried loading the file in an `AppDomain` using the code below:

```
AppDomain dom = AppDomain.CreateDomain("assemblyLoadDomain");
AssemblyName assemblyName = new AssemblyName();
assemblyName.CodeBase = assemblyPath;
Assembly assembly = dom.Load(assemblyName);

// do operation here

AppDomain.Unload(dom);
```

**This starts searching for the assembly in the application startup path, rather than the path defined in `assemblyPath`. And gives a FileNotFound Exception if not found. I verified this using Process Explorer as well: It also shows the assembly in the startup path being loaded**

Also the assembly isn't being unloaded.

What am I doing wrong ???

Comment: You should not pass `Assembly` object back to main `AppDomain`, because this require to load assembly in main `AppDomain` too.

Comment: @PetSerAl I'm not passing the assembly object to the main `AppDomain`. I'm just reading a string (returned from a function in the assembly) and unloading the assembly. I want to update this string in the new assembly that I generate

Comment: *I'm not passing the assembly object to the main `AppDomain`.* You are: `Assembly assembly = dom.Load(assemblyName);`

Comment: @PetSerAl oh okay. So how can I load the file, execute a function, and unload the file (so I can replace the file) ??

Comment: and if I don't use `Assembly assembly = ....`, how will I be able to use the `GetType()` and `GetMethod()` functions ?

Comment: You should do all that in the other domain and do not pass back to main domain any intermediate `Assembly`, `Type` or `MethodInfo` object.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/164485/discussion-between-mrid-and-petseral).